# My mongoDB is not working it execute error

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed
```

I expect to work this mongodb

Comment: How do you connect? Is your MongoDB running?

Answer (score 0):

Windows environment:

If you are using on localhost then start the mongod process, from the bin location(the location where you installed mongodb)

`"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.exe"` default path location
keep this terminal running, do not close it

After that open the mongo shell, download from offical mongodb website install it, and connect your localhost

in Linux environment :

Maybe your server might not be working, restart the service.
As you are not able to log in to the system so kill the process.

in linux terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep mongo
```

get the process id number, then kill the process

```
kill pid_number
```

After that start it from its config file
in terminal pass this command, and change the path of mongod.conf file if it is not installed on default location.

```
mongod --config=/etc/mongod.conf
```

(this one is default path)

Hope this will work.

Comment: `/etc/mongod.conf` is not the **default**. If you don't specify `--config` then no configuration file is used.

Comment: appreciated sir, but by mentioning --config and config file path, mentioned problem statement might solved.